# jQuery UI Slider setting value with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using jQueryUI Slider plugin to choose a value from a set of values.

Let's say I have a slider with 5 values. I want to achieve effect similar to this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#hotelrooms , but I want the slider-handle to move smoothly between values, and if the handle is dropped between two values, it should snap to the closest

I've come up with a workaround, but it seems that there's something wrong with it. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Tw9U/10/). I set the minimum value to 1, maximum to 500 to get a smooth sliding effect on dragging, and then, on stop event check if the value is equal to 100 (just for now, to keep it simple), if it's not, set the value of slider to 100. It all works fine, but there's no nice smooth sliding effect even though I set the animate value to 500.

Is there a way to get it done with this workaround? Or should I rather try something else?
Feel free to use and change my jsfiddle.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is wrong with this animation? I see a smooth sliding effect. What more do you want with this sliding animation?

Comment: If you drag the handle e.g from 0 to 400, it goes back to 100 without animation. http://jsfiddle.net/6Tw9U/10/

Comment: Does this does the trick? http://jsfiddle.net/6Tw9U/13/

Comment: I dont see any diffrence in code. Can you please save your work, or paste the code here?

Comment: Added it as an answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tomasdev/6Tw9U/21/ Perhaps you were missing the `step` property?

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATE

Here is a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Tw9U/22/) using steps and setTimeout to make digits changes smoothly. Depending on what are your real steps, you have to adjust setTimeout speed and the speed of increasing digits in smoothDigitIncrease().

Comment: there's still no animation between neighboring values. The thing is, the step value must be set to 1, because I need to see the value changing. But it can't stop somewhere between 100 and 200. It has to snap to one or the other.

Comment: @user1708722 Check my new fiddle, hope it is more what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, we're almost there. The step value must be set to 1, to get that nice smooth effect while dragging. That's missing.

Comment: @user1708722 I've updated [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Tw9U/22/) with a step set to 1. I've adjusted timeout delai with the increasing speed to have something better.

Comment: But I also need the handle to snap to defined values. E.g 100, 200 etc. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @user1708722 I think it's bad since it's not the way the plugin is mean to work, it should be set on the step option. I think it's possible to hack the slider to have something near the way you want but it won't be optimised. You should consider take another slider.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

instead of directly assigning the new value go in incremental way for e.g.

current value =1

value to be set = 5

loop from 1 to 5 instead of setting direct with a 100 or 400 millisecond delay in each

Comment: thanks, good thinking, but there's a chance that I'd have to go through the loop 100 times and I'm afraid it would kill my browser.

Comment: no it will not kill. see the other guy has posted the demo with same method its working awesome